# Java где Spring ищет файлы конфигурации

Tags: java, spring

Хочу разобраться с конфигурацией в спринге. У меня есть такой main-класс:

```
package knights;

import knights.base.Knight;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class KnightsMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/knight.xml");
        Knight knight = context.getBean(Knight.class);
        knight.embarkOnQuest();
        context.close();
    }
}
```

И структура директорий выглядит так:

```
.
|-- META-INF
|   |-- MANIFEST.MF
|   `-- spring
|       `-- knight.xml
|-- Spring.iml
|-- pom.xml
|-- src
|   |-- main
|   |   |-- java
|   |   |   |-- knights
|   |   |   |   |-- BraveKnight.java
|   |   |   |   |-- KnightsMain.java
|   |   |   |   |-- RescueDamselQuest.java
|   |   |   |   |-- SlayDragonQuest.java
|   |   |   |   |-- base
|   |   |   |   |   |-- Knight.java
|   |   |   |   |   `-- Quest.java
|   |   |   |   `-- config
|   |   |   |       `-- KnightsConfig.java
|   |   |   `-- main
|   |   |       `-- Main.java
|   |   `-- resources
|   |       |-- course.xml
|   |       `-- knight.xml
|   `-- test
|       `-- java
|           `-- knights
|               `-- BraveKnightTest.java
```

При запуске получаю ошибку:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/spring/knight.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
```

Почему спринг не может найти xml-файл? Откуда он начинает поиск?

Comment: Смотрит в ресурсы проекта т.е. в main/resource

Comment: META-INF обычно является подкаталогом resources, да и MANIFEST.MF руками обычно не создают.

Answer (score -2):

Положите файл `knight.xml` в папку `src/main/java` и

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:knight.xml");
```

Comment: Обычно в java конфиги не кладут.